# Error al ejecutar la sentencia "rake" en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi instalación de *Rails 4.1.0* y *Ruby 2.4.0*. Pude correr `bundle install`, pero al dar:

```
rake db:create
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>      rake aborted!
>      Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'devise'.
>      Gem Load Error is: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
>       Backtrace for gem load error is:
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in `*'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in`days'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:55:in `weeks'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:131:in`'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`require'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`each'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in`require'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'<br/>
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/Rakefile:4:in`'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in`load_rakefile'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in`block in load_rakefile'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in`load_rakefile'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in`standard_exception_handling'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'<br/>
>      /Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in`'
>      Bundler Error Backtrace:
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
>       /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/Rakefile:4:in`'
>       TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
>   /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
>       /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/APPS/lapapaya/lapapaya/Rakefile:4:in`'
>       (See full trace by running task with --trace)

¿Qué es lo que está sucediendo?

Comment: Esto es StackOverflow en Español, debe traducir su pregunta a este idioma

Comment: Ya la traduje, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que Ruby 2.4.0 no está soportado correctamente en Rails 4.1.0 (creo que es a partir de Rails 4.2.0 donde ya se soporta). Instala Ruby 2.3.4 y no tendrás problema.

Claro que si es un app nueva, te recomiendo ir con Rails 5 o, en su defecto, Rails 4.2.8 (ambas versiones compatibles con Ruby 2.4.0).

Comment: Excelente! Me corrió con ruby 2.3.4 gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Tuve que cambiar de sistema operativo por que windows no estaba soportando bien varias gemas de mi ruby, de modo que cree un bash de ubuntu sobre windows y ahora todo va de maravilla!
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto, yo creo que no hace falta que cambies de versión de ruby.

`bind/rails db:migrate`